# Symfony2 + Capifony rolling back error

Tags: symfony, rollback, capifony

I configured Capifony to deploy to my remote servers and when I deploy project  I get some error after capifony has execution an rolling back operation. 
But after capifony executed `symfony:composer:dump_autoload` action and consequently it dump chache and autoload files **with new release path**. After when I run symfony application I get error:

`PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening '/var/www/vhosts/user/app/releases/20130805162052/src/Rocket/ApplicationBundle/RocketApplicationBundle.php' for inclusion (include_path='/........') in /var/www/vhosts/user/app/shared/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 185`

So the question: how I can execute `symfony:composer:dump_autoload` if  deploy  got any error

Something like this:

`after "deploy:rolling_back_action", "symfony:composer:dump_autoload"`

Can anyone help me?

**EDIT**:

I tried to redeclare namespace `:deploy:update_code` and change `on_rollback` action, in current deploying session if I getting any error this hook is work. but when executing`symfony:composer:dump_autoload` action in on_rollback event `releas_path` is not current, and I can't his redeclare... Here is my code, when I tryed redeclare namespace:

```
namespace :deploy do
     task :update_code, :except => { :no_release => true } do
         on_rollback { my_namespace.rollback }
        strategy.deploy!
        finalize_update
     end
 end

 namespace :my_namespace do

  task :rollback, :except => { :no_release => true } do
        run "rm -rf #{release_path}; true" #default capistrano action on rollback

        #my custom actions
        #run "cd "+shared_path+"/../current"
        #run "php composer.phar dump-autoload"

        set :release_path, shared_path+"/../current"
        symfony.composer.dump_autoload
  end
 end
```

So far I have found a temporary solution to this problem - each time after deploy execute `cap symfony:composer:dump_autoload` to update the paths and dump new autoload info, but it I don't like...

Can I reach the truth with re declare namespace or with other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

you can continue the task if errors occur using something like this:

```
namespace :symfony do 
    namespace :composer: do 
        task :dump_autoload, :on_error => :continue do 
             /* parent task */ 
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks you @nifr for your answer, I answered and explained in detail in its issue...